# WSO2 IS - Retrieve challenge questions of a user and Configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

1. We are currently using WSO2 IS 5.10.
2. We are storing all the challenge questions as showing below

   **/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection**
   [image]
3. We are using **getChallengeQuestionsOfUser** SOAP(**UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl)** API for retrieving the challenge questions of a particular user by passing username as input parameter and getting only three security questions as response.

   **getChallengeQuestionsOfUser(userName)**
4. **The API is returning only 3 security Questions, is there any configuration to retrieve more than 3?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Fist verify the `questionSetId` property value of the questions stored at location `/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection`.
   [image]
2. If you wish to set more than 3 challenge question for a user, there should be questions in more than 3 `questionSetId`s at this location. Prior to that you should have created a local claim URI for each questionSetId.
3. Let's say this is the user's selected question from each questionSetId. and called `setChallengeQuestionsOfUser` API.
   [image]
4. Verify the set challenge questions for the user from the above soap API.  Mark supported by default true for the challenge question-related claims under local claims and check on user profile.
   [image]
5. The challenge question claim values set for the user, will be returned when getChallengeQuestionsOfUser SOAP API is invoked

[image]

If I answer to your question of

> The API is returning only 3 security Questions

It should be because the user has set only 3 challenge question answers. May be you have questions at `/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection` with some other`questionSetId`. but that particular tested user has picked only challenge questions from only 3 `questionSetId`s